# Replace para html

Tags: php

Daí Galera, vejam meu código:

```
<--php-->
$nomeusuario = print($_SESSION['nome']);
$html = str_replace('#NOMEUSUARIO#', $nomeusuario, $html);

<--html-->
Olá, <strong>#NOMEUSUARIO#</strong> seja bem vindo
```

O nome do usuário fica no topo da página, e não na tag  que gostaria. Como que substituo o #NOMEUSUARIO# para pegar a string 'nome' do print($_SESSION['nome'] não posso deixar o arquivo html em php, pois uso MVC.

Vejam abaixo como fica.

[image]

Obrigado.

Comment: Não entendi. 
O que tem no $html antes do str_replace?
E a forma correta para atribuir o valor à variável $nomeusuario é:
$nomeusuario = $_SESSION['nome'];

Answer (score 2):

Irei listar dois erros existentes:

**1. Print():**

Primeiramente neste caso o `print` não é correto, apenas remova.

```
<--php-->
$nomeusuario = $_SESSION['nome'];
$html = str_replace('#NOMEUSUARIO#', $nomeusuario, $html);

<--html-->
Olá, <strong>#NOMEUSUARIO#</strong> seja bem vindo
```

O motivo disso é simples.
Quando se usa o `print` estará literalmente exibindo o conteúdo.

Não entendeu?
Veja este exemplo:

```
$qualquer_coisa = print('meu_nome');
```

Isso irá exibir `meu_nome` no arquivo, geralmente no inicio uma vez que o html está depois dessa função. Mas, o resultado irá ser exibido onde é chamado.

E a variável `$qualquer_coisa`? Essa irá possuir o valor `1`, CASO estivesse funcionando perfeitamente, o `#NOMEUSUARIO#` seria substituído por `1`.

**2. $html?!**

Existe um detalhe, que não sei se foi criado por você ao postar a pergunta, mas estarei considerando um erro.

O que a variável `$html` possui? Nada.

Para solucionar aconselho fazer dois arquivos, por exemplo:

Um arquivo para salvar puramente o HTML:

> /public_html/html_index.html ~ Exemplo, mas deixe antes do public_html!

```
Olá, <strong>#NOMEUSUARIO#</strong> seja bem vindo
```

> /public_html/index.php

```
$nomeusuario = $_SESSION['nome'];

$arquivo = 'html_index.html'; 
// Caminho de exemplo!    

$html = file_get_contents( $arquivo );
// Carrega o HTML, do outro arquivo.

$html = str_replace('#NOMEUSUARIO#', $nomeusuario, $html);

echo $html;
// Exibe o HTML, já alterado.
```

Por que isso?

O `file_get_contents()` irá obter o HTML do outro arquivo, que é puramente HTML, por isso o `str_replace()` irá justamente substituir o conteúdo que foi carregado anteriormente.

Comment: Não compreendi o porque fazer isso. Já tenho os arquivos html, só preciso fazer um replace de uma variável do php e jogar no html. Tipo assim.

No php --------------------------------------------------------------------------------

$nomeusuario = $_SESSION['nome'];

$html = str_replace('#NOMEUSUARIO#', $nomeusuario);

No html---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
<strong>#NOMEUSUARIO#</strong>

Comment: Você pode ter o HTML, mas ele não é mencionado. O PHP só pode manipular o que está setado. Não há como fazer a substituição sem que antes carregue o texto. Por exemplo: "Eu falo biscoito", se quiser trocar por "biscoito" por "bolacha" terá que PRIMEIRO definir alguma variavel para ter a frase "Eu falo biscoito". Caso contrario não há como definir. Logico, se tiver noção minima poderá fazer um `file_get_contents` no próprio arquivo e então "encontrar" o html (até mesmo fazer um `explode` básico no `<--html-->`) e então uma variável irá ter o HTML do arquivo. Mas isso vai depender de você.

Comment: Valeu pela ajuda amigo. Estou iniciando em php. Consegui fazer de outra maneira, com o menu sendo feito no php direto, na classe Menu. Não precisando carregar um arquivo html. Obrigado.

Answer (score -1):

Olá. Você pode fazer para exibir o nome do usuário com o próprio php, desta maneira:

> php

```
$nomeusuario = $_SESSION['nome'];
```

> html

```
Olá, <strong><?php echo $nomeusuario; ?></strong> seja bem vindo
```

Comment: Não funciona no modo MVC, não posso alterar a estrutura do html.